# CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4 not serving content after change of root web directory

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, webserver

I'm trying to change an apache web service's root web directory `/var/www/html` to my custom directory `/mnt/webfiles`. However, after configuring the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` parameters and restarting `httpd`, my test directory/files still cannot be browsed from webpage.

Here's the environment:
OS: CentOS 7.9.2009
Apache version: 2.4.6
The installation type of OS: Basic web server

The purpose of using the apache web is just for test and there's no specific domain name requirement on this server, just IP address for client to browse web.

When I use the default directory `/var/www/html` to put test files, such as a simple .txt acting as simple webpage or a sub-directory `download` with a file in it to simulate download page, every thing works just fine. The webpage can be browsed via browser.

But, after changing `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` and `Directory "/var/www"`to my specific directory `/mnt/webfiles`, the test files/directories under `/mnt/webfiles` can never be accessed and the error message showed on browser would be like:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /download/ on this server.
```

Only the default apache webpage can be browsed and not affected.

What I did was following the instrucitons from [this post](https://www.tecmint.com/change-root-directory-of-apache-web-server/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server),

By the way, the permission of the files/directorues all the way from the root directory of apache web is `root:root` and `775`, basically same as the `/var/www/html`.
I guess this is not the root cause.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible answer would be that SELinux is denying the new webroot.

Check if SELinux is enabled:

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing
```

`Enforcing` means that SELinux is enabled and enforcing the rules. A quick check to see if SElinux is *really*  the problem would be to temporarily disable it:

```
$ setenforce 0
```

Reload the webpage and if it works now, SELinux is most likely the culprit.

But how to fix this permanently *without* having to disable SELinux?

Check the *correct* context of a webroot:

```
$ ll -Z /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ..
```

Notice the `httpd_sys_content_t` tag!

This probably differs from your new webroot at `/mnt/webfiles`.

You need to define a correct context for the new webroot in the SELinux policy. Do this:

```
# This sets correct context in the policy
$ semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/mnt/webfiles(/.*)?" 

# This applies the context to the webroot
$ restorecon -v /mnt/webfiles
```

Then check if it worked. Remember to re-enable SELinux otherwise you won't be actually testing it :-)

```
$ setenforce 1
```

To check for denials, you can view the SELinux AVC denial log like so:

```
$ ausearch -ts recent -m avc
```

Also, if you need write access to the webroot, you may need to change the context from `httpd_sys_content_t` to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` OR set the `httpd_unified` SELinux boolean to `true`:

```
$ setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Comment: Spot on for using `setenforce 0` only for diagnostics

Comment: thank you so much. However, I found solution before seeing this post, which is ```chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /mnt/webfiles```, but I'm still trying to understand the meaning. Anyway, the issue just solved via using this commnad.

Comment: @user53815 'chcon' indeed works, but is a _temporary_ solution because it doesn't persist. Should the filesystem get relabeled for some reason, the SELinux policy will overwrite the contexts with the detault ones. If you run the `semanage` command I provided, that risk will be avoided. A good explanation can be found at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext. Good luck!